# why Shortcut without pressing the alt key

Tags: delphi

I have a simple application 2 Labels, 2 Edits and a button.

[image]

if i press alt+1 or alt+2 the focus jumps to Edit1 or edit2.

if the button1 has the focus and i press 1 (without alt) it jump to edit1.

that make some problems. it is possible to disable that. it was not so in borland c++ 6.0.

thanks

Comment: I've never heard of this behavior. Typing `1` should enter `1` in the edit, as designed. Does your Windows have Sticky Keys enabled? Do you have any event handlers on these controls?

Comment: That does not happen normally. Please [edit] your post to include your .DFM (as text) and your code (again, as text) so that we can attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: These are known as accelerator key presses and not shortcuts, btw.

Comment: @JerryDodge The button has the focus. So no, typing `1` should not enter anything in any edit control.

Comment: That will happen if button1 has the focus. If edit1 has the focus it is ok.

Comment: Try this with the "Run" dialog of the shell: navigate away from the "open" combo to the "ok" or "cancel" buttons, then press 'b' (or whatever is the accelerator key for your browse button).

Comment: Or just create a new VCL form with three buttons, captioned `&Alpha`, `&Beta`, and `&Gamma`.

Answer (score 5):

> *why Shortcut without pressing the alt key*

The VCL emulates OS behavior. What it emulates is explained in dialog box [navigation topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlgbox/dlgbox-programming-considerations#mnemonics):

> A mnemonic is a selected letter or digit in the label of a button or
>   in the text of a static control. The system moves the input focus to
>   the control associated with the mnemonic whenever the user either
>   presses the key that corresponds to the mnemonic or presses this key
>   and the ALT key in combination.

As you can see pressing the ALT key is not a requirement for a mnemonic to move the focus. For this to happen, though, the already focused control should not be interested in the pressed key. This is explained a bit further down:

> When the user presses a letter or digit key, the system first
>   determines whether the current control having the input focus
>   processes the key. The system sends a WM_GETDLGCODE message to the
>   control, and if the control returns the DLGC_WANTALLKEYS or
>   DLG_WANTMESSAGE value, the system passes the key to the control.
>   Otherwise, it searches for a control whose mnemonic matches the
>   specified letter or digit.

This is what happens when you press "1". The button does not process the key, so the VCL searches for a control who does.

> *it is possible to disable that*

VCL emulates the behavior by performing a [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) on a `TWinControl` while handling a `CN_CHAR` message (a mutated `WM_CHAR`). If the control's response does not include `DLGC_WANTCHARS` then the control performs a `CM_DIALOGCHAR` on the parent form. The form sends the message to all its controls until/if one of them wants to handle it.

This is one place where you can override the behavior, you can test if the ALT key is pressed and halt processing if it is not.  A `CM_DIALOGCHAR` uses the same structure as a [`WM_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-char), so bit 29 of `lParam` specifies if ALT key is pressed or not.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  protected
    procedure CMDialogChar(var Message: TCMDialogChar); message CM_DIALOGCHAR;
  ...

procedure TForm1.CMDialogChar(var Message: TCMDialogChar);
begin
  if Boolean(Message.KeyData shr 29 and 1) then
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: But please don't disable this. If I am in a dialog box containing a button captioned `&Compute`, and I press `C` when a button (say) has keyboard focus, I sure expect the dialog box to start the computation!

Comment: btw: Starting from Windows 8.1 (possibly earlier) the default behavior for (Windows) dialogs is that these shortcuts only work if you press Alt+Character. At least that's what I see e.g. in the "Dialog" I get when I press Ctrl+Alt+Del. For Delphi-Dialogs the behavior is unchanged, it works with and without the Alt key (and I prefer it that way).

Comment: @dumm - The lock screen behaves the same on W7. I think you'll find the behavior have not changed at all if you test, f.i., with the "run" dialog like I commented to the question.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Hm, yes, apparently it hasn't changed in all dialogs. The Lock dialog used to work without Alt in Windows XP and it is the one system dialog I use very often, so that's probably why I thought the default behaviour had changed.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is by design. When a control which does not accept input has the focus, key presses are interpreted as accelerator key presses.

Comment: Design is by the OS BTW, not VCL, if it is not evident.

Comment: @Sertac Yes. It's also worth noting that this behaviour is implemented in the VCL.